# How to store function output into <tr></tr> element

Tags: javascript, html

I'm working on a simple expense tracker project.
I need to store the output of createAlltd() in a new  element every time i click btn and attach it to  element. So far i only managed to store all td's into tbody but without tr element and vice versa.

```
const exp = document.querySelector('.addExpense'); //tbody
const expInp = document.querySelector('.expense');
const dateInp = document.querySelector('.date');
const amountInp = document.querySelector('.amount');
const btn = document.querySelector('.btn');

function createTd(e){
     var td = document.createElement('td');;
     td.innerText = e.value;
     e.value = "";
}

function createTr(){
    var newTr = document.createElement('tr');
    newTr.className = ".newTr";
    exp.append(newTr);
}

function createAllTd(){ 
    createTd(expInp); 
    createTd(dateInp); 
    createTd(amountInp);
   
  
}


btn.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();  
        createTr();
        createAllTd();
        expInp.focus();
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Yor problem is that you create separated elements of tr and td but not append the td's to relevant tr.
Use function .appendChild() fo this, like:

```
 tr.appendChild(td);
```

I updated your code, see below. Put attention - the functions to crate row and cells now have return values. And event listener uses those values to append the cells to the row.

Unfortunately, I can't test the solution because of missing HTML and data at the question.

```
const exp = document.querySelector('.addExpense'); //tbody
const expInp = document.querySelector('.expense');
const dateInp = document.querySelector('.date');
const amountInp = document.querySelector('.amount');
const btn = document.querySelector('.btn');

function createTd(e){
     var td = document.createElement('td');;
     td.innerText = e.value;
     e.value = "";
}

function createTr(){
    var newTr = document.createElement('tr');
    newTr.className = ".newTr";
    exp.append(newTr);
    return newTr;
}

function createAllTd(){ 
    let tds = [];
    tds.push(createTd(expInp)); 
    tds.push(reateTd(dateInp)); 
    tds.push(createTd(amountInp));
    return tds;
}


btn.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();  
        let row = createTr();
        let cells = createAllTd();
        cells.forEach(cell => {
            row.appendChild(cell);
        })
        expInp.focus();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

So what you need to do is somehow fetch the row that you have created and then add the columns to that row.

Hence We can change the `createTr()` function to return the freshly appended row by fetching the lastElement inside `<tbody>`. Hence the function would now look like:

```
function createTr(){
    var newTr = document.createElement('tr');
    newTr.className = ".newTr";
    exp.append(newTr);
    return newTr;
}
```

now that we have the access to the newly created row via code, we can pass this to our `createAllTd()` function and from there to `createTd()` and append the `<td>` to the `<tr>` element as now available. Hence the functions now look like the following:

```
function createTd(e, elNewTr){
     var td = document.createElement('td');;
     td.innerText = e.value;
     e.value = "";
     // This statement appends the TD inside the TR as passed in the parameter
     elNewTr.append(td);
}

function createAllTd(elNewTr){
    // Pass the newly created TR element to the TD functions so that we can append TD inside the new TR 
    createTd(expInp, elNewTr); 
    createTd(dateInp, elNewTr); 
    createTd(amountInp, elNewTr);
}
```

Hence the final code now looks like this:

```
const exp = document.querySelector('.addExpense'); //tbody
const expInp = document.querySelector('.expense');
const dateInp = document.querySelector('.date');
const amountInp = document.querySelector('.amount');
const btn = document.querySelector('.btn');


function createTd(e, elNewTr){
     var td = document.createElement('td');;
     td.innerText = e.value;
     e.value = "";
     // This statement appends the TD inside the TR as passed in the parameter
     elNewTr.append(td);
}

function createTr(){
    var newTr = document.createElement('tr');
    newTr.className = ".newTr";
    exp.append(newTr);
    return newTr;
}

function createAllTd(elNewTr){
    // Pass the newly created TR element to the TD functions so that we can append TD inside the new TR 
    createTd(expInp, elNewTr); 
    createTd(dateInp, elNewTr); 
    createTd(amountInp, elNewTr);
}

btn.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        e.preventDefault(); 
        // Catch the new TR element as returned 
        elNewTr = createTr();
        // Pass it to the TD creation process for usage
        createAllTd(elNewTr);
        expInp.focus();
    });
```

This should do it.